# Change symfony2 form field but keep relation

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

So I have a form that is based on an entity that contains a one to many relationship.

The problem is that this field is rendered as a select (or choice). I really don't want to load all the possible ids (there are many) but just want to load the one that is set in the entity (which is the id that appears selected in the select).

Is there any way of doing this and still keep the relationship? If I really have to change the field how can I access, in the form class, the selected entity given to the entity so that I can retrieve the id?

**UPDATE**

To make this a bit clearer here is my form code:

```
$this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('items', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new \MyBundle\Form\ItemsType(),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'data' => $itemsEntities
            )
    )
    ->add('submit', 'submit')
```

In the $itemsEntities I have 5 entities all of which generate the select with loads of ids. Hakins answer would work I think if this would be just one field but since there are many I don't really know how to handle this.

I have tried to put an eventListner on the  \MyBundle\Form\ItemsType for but I can never access any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the id of the related entity to the form builder parameters, and change your field type to `hidden` instead of `choice` (or `entity`):

In your controller:

```
$id = $entity->getRelatedEntity()->getId();
$options['id'] = $id;
$form = $this->createForm(new EntityType($options), $entity);
```

In your EntityType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $options = $this->options;
    $builder
            ->add('relatedEntity', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => $options['id'],
                'required' => TRUE
            ));
```

---

### Update

To avoid rendering **a collection** without changing the relationship, you can change only your Twig form by rendering the selected item(s) id(s) as hidden field(s), then set `rendered` the form.items. (If you don't set them `rendered`, they will be present in the `form_rest(form)`)

With your existing code for the formBuilder, change your twig like this:

```
{% block body %}
    ...
    {% for item in form.items %}
          {% if item.vars.data %}
              <input type="hidden" name="{{ item.vars.full_name}}" id="{{ item.vars.id }}" value="{{ item.vars.value }}"
          {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% do form.items.setRendered %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. This seems like the correct approach but I need to print only the selected id and not every id as an input. I will try this out (with a few changes) and if successful I will set this answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @AntonioCS you're right, look at my last update to render only the selected id (item.vars.data true)

Comment: I have set this answer as the correct one because this guided me to the correct answer. I didn't need the for I just needed to create the input and do {{ item.vars.value }} (not with item but with the correct name of the form item) and the correct value would be printed without the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could use the 'query_builder' option of the field (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) and create a query that fetches the only result you want, based on it's id. You could pass the id to the constructor of form if necessary.

Comment: The problem is that I am using a collection. So for each collection I have different ids. I am trying to use  event listeners but with no succcess